# Loading javascript dynamically based on the http or https protocol

Tags: javascript, html, https, internet-explorer-8

I have a javascript file located in a different server, and I am including the javascript file over `http` page like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/scriptfile.js">
```

or over `https` page like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com/scriptfile.js">
```

The problem is, that I have page switching from `http` to `https`, for example, if a user is in

`http://www.example.com/home`(site home URL) and I load the javascript over `http`, now when the user navigates to another page like `https://www.example.com/transaction` (site transaction URL), I load the script over `https` and its working fine. From the mentioned transaction URL if the user hits the `https://www.example.com/home` (home URL changed to `https`), the script which I loaded over `http` fails because of unsecured content. Any suggestion to handle this is welcomed.

Comment: The trivial solution would be to get rid of all unsecured content - just use https:// throughout your site, and turn off port 80.

Comment: @Floris I loaded the javascript with 'https' regardless of the page protocol and it worked fine. thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The protocol is optional. If you omit it, the browser will use whatever the document's protocol is.  So you can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.mydomain.com/scriptfile.js">
```

The correct protocol will be used.

Answer (score 5):

Use a protocol-relative URL for your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.mydomain.com/scriptfile.js">
```

This will use the same protocol as the calling page.